# BeatifulSoup, WebScraping , Imgaes

Tags: python

Hi i am learning webscraping in python and I faced a problem when I am trying to **scrape** some images from a website called pexel nothing is showing up on the terminal however when I tried another website with the same code it worked any ideas why is that happening?
and here is the code which was the same for both states I only changed the URL.

```
from bs4 import *
import requests as rq
import os
req = rq.get('https://unsplash.com/s/photos/earth').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req,'lxml')

links = []

k = soup.select('img[src^="https://images.unsplash.com/photo"]')
for s in k:
    print(s)
```

and After I was able to scrape the images from the unsplash website it only scraped 15 images and half of them were repeated is there a way to scrape more than this if so > How ?
and when I request the webpage does the whole page being downloaded I mean when you open a page sometimes you need to scroll down, and then some of the images get downloaded is those ones that you need to scroll down being downloaded when I am making the request ?

It was a long question thanks for you time ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I have tried scroll to bottom in unsplash then i found see some urls is always getting called named as following,

1. https://unsplash.com/napi/search/photos?query=earth&per_page=20&page=2&xp=
2. https://unsplash.com/napi/search/photos?query=earth&per_page=20&page=2&xp=
3. etc.

Please check out XHR in Network section. If your concern is to get the images related to an query or please do let me know if i am wrongly understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the `selenium` library for your jobs.

Comment: This ought be a comment! The reasons are 1/ that it does not help answer the problem. 2/ `selunium` is an overkill for such a task. The major issue is though not showing how he/she can use `selinium` to over come the issue he/she faces.